# Standalone multiline logo

Tags: graphics, standalone, transparency, svg

I would like to produce through pdflatex an image that shrink-wraps around a logo.

Here is a skeleton file.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\begin{document}
line 1

line 2
\end{document}
```

But this produces

[image: Line 1 and Line 2 appear on one line.]

How do I specify that the two lines should be on separate lines?

Comment: @egreg -- i agree that the cited question is a duplicate, but some of the answers here don't appear there.  it would be good to consolidate.